# Symbol behind the .js

Tags: javascript

What is "?_=3.5-SNAPSHOT-Dev" mean after ".js"? I do some research on google but no idea what it mean and what it use for

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.js?_=3.5-SNAPSHOT-Dev"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the server that's serving your Javascript. Generally, variables like those on JS files are used for cache busting. I think in your example, `3.5-SNAPSHOT-Dev` could be a release tag. If this JS file is now on your own machine, you can safely discard the `?` and anything after that. If you're getting this from another server somewhere, seek out documentation about that server to see what they use the `_` variable for.